# Purpose of unsigned integers

Tags: java, char, integer, unsigned-integer

I know the meaning of *unsigned integers*. Those are possible values for data types which only accept non-negative integers. I want to know the usage of them.

[Concepts of Programming Languages (12th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134997182) says:

> Unsigned types are often used for binary data.

Now what is the meaning of *binary data* expression in above quote?

As we use different data types for storing data, I am sure that the meaning of *binary data* expression in above quote is **not**:

> Binary data is a type of data that is represented or displayed in the binary numeral system.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_data) says:

> In applied computer science and in the information technology field, the term binary data is often specifically *opposed* to text-based data, referring to any sort of data that *cannot* be interpreted as text.

If it is true, why Java use *16-bit unsigned integers* as value for `char` data type for representing *character*s which are text based data? [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) says:

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, ... and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73564601/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/153939/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: "often" does not mean "always".

Comment: 'Why Java use 16-bit unsigned integers as value for char': because there is no such thing as a negative UTF-16 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main usage of the unsigned integers is obviously the representation of the *natural* numbers. They are used, among others, for counting and representing discrete quantities.

Note that the concepts of signedness and binary representation are orthogonal. In fact, the signed numbers share the same representation (a sequence of bits) and only the interpretation when doing arithmetic differs.

AFAIK, very few programming languages support unsigned integers, though IMO it is fundamental type.

---

The quote "often used for binary data" is a little misleading, as it relates to the fact that integer variables often have a length that is a multiple of a byte, the "unit" of raw information. When dealing with raw data, it is most of the times irrelevant, if not problematic, to consider signed values.